# Playing an incoming RTP stream with GStreamer

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

I'm developing a GStreamer application and struggling bit with implementing a player for incoming RTP streams. I am trying to construct a pipeline around the gstrtpbin element. I'm trying to model the pipeline using a gst-launch construction:

```
VIDEO_CAPS="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264"

gst-launch -v udpsrc caps=$VIDEO_CAPS port=4444 \
              ! gstrtpbin .recv_rtp_sink_0 \
              ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink
```

When I launch the script GStreamer reports these errors:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpSession:rtpsession0: ntp-ns-base = 3469468914024449000
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpSession:rtpsession0.GstPad:recv_rtp_sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0.GstGhostPad:recv_rtp_sink_0: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0.GstGhostPad:recv_rtp_sink_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad0: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpSession:rtpsession0.GstPad:recv_rtp_src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpSsrcDemux:rtpssrcdemux0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpPtDemux:rtpptdemux0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0.GstGhostPad:recv_rtp_src_0_960476599_33.GstProxyPad:proxypad1: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)33
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2378): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
Execution ended after 209381685 ns.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0.GstGhostPad:recv_rtp_src_0_960476599_33: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpPtDemux:rtpptdemux0.GstPad:src_33: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpPtDemux:rtpptdemux0.GstPad:sink: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0.GstPad:sink: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0.GstPad:src: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpSsrcDemux:rtpssrcdemux0.GstPad:src_960476599: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpSsrcDemux:rtpssrcdemux0.GstPad:sink: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpSession:rtpsession0.GstPad:recv_rtp_src: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpSession:rtpsession0.GstPad:recv_rtp_sink: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0.GstGhostPad:recv_rtp_sink_0: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = NULL
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I should mention that it works with a playbin and SDP file. For example this file:

```
v=0
o=- 1188340656180883 1 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=Session streamed by GStreamer
i=server.sh
t=0 0
a=tool:GStreamer
a=type:broadcast
m=video 4444 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

Can be used to play the stream like this:

```
gst-launch -vvv playbin uri=file://`pwd`/stream.sdp
```

For completeness: I am using VLC to send data. This is the command:

```
vlc -I rc /usr/local/movies/sample.mp4 \
    --screen-fps=10 :screen-caching=100 \
    --sout='#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{bframes=0,keyint=40},vb=512}:\
                   rtp{mux=ts,dst=127.0.0.1,port=4444}'
```

Would someone help me understand why the gst-launch script fails? The error "reason not-linked" makes me think that the link between gstrtpbin and the rtph264depay elements is broken. But I don't know how to fix it.

**Edit**
Following RAOF's suggestions I fixed a few errors in my command. However I am using ffdec_h264 and autovideosink because on my Windows system I don't have the fluh264dec and xvimage sink plugins installed:

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=4444 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264" ! .recv_rtp_sink_0 gstrtpbin ! rtpmp2tdepay ! mpegtsdemux ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

Which leads to new errors:

```
0:00:00.743000000   516   024070A8 ERROR                 ffmpeg .:0:: non-existing PPS referenced
0:00:00.744000000   516   024070A8 ERROR                 ffmpeg .:0:: non-existing PPS referenced
0:00:00.745000000   516   024070A8 ERROR                 ffmpeg .:0:: decode_slice_header error
0:00:00.745000000   516   024070A8 ERROR                 ffmpeg .:0:: no frame!
0:00:00.812000000   516   024070A8 ERROR                 ffmpeg .:0:: non-existing PPS referenced
0:00:00.813000000   516   024070A8 ERROR                 ffmpeg .:0:: non-existi
...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow
 error.
Additional debug info:
..\Source\gstreamer\libs\gst\base\gstbasesrc.c(2378): gst_base_src_loop (): /Gst
Pipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 4790000000 ns.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to fix this. If you can help, then feel free to do so.

**Edit2**
I tested again using the SDP solution and observed that the "non-existing PPS" errors also occur, but the video does play. On the other hand, the fatal "internal data flow error" only shows when using the custom pipeline solution.
I suspect that the "non-existing PPS" errors are caused by the x264 encoder. The "internal data flow error" must be caused by an error in my pipeline, or perhaps a bug in some Windows plugin. I'll so some further research...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you've got two problems there:

Firstly, it seems the order of sink specification is important: rather than `... ! gstrtpbin .recv_rtp_sink_0 ! ...` you need to have `... ! .recv_rtp_sink_0 gstrtpbin ! ...`.

Secondly, vlc is sending an MPEG2 transport stream - you've got `mux=ts` in the rtp streaming output descriptor - but you're trying to depayload a raw h264 stream.  You need to depayload the ts stream, and then demux it to get at the h264 stream data.

So, finally, the pipeline

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v udpsrc port=4444 \
caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264" \
! .recv_rtp_sink_0 gstrtpbin ! rtpmp2tdepay \
! mpegtsdemux ! fluh264dec ! xvimagesink
```

works for me, using the TS demuxer (mpegtsdemux) and h264 decoder (fluh264dec).

Comment: I've now installed gstreamer-ffmpeg and tried it with ffdec_h264 and autovideosink.  My pipeline works for me with those elements instead of fluh264dec and xvimagesink.  I'm not sure where your problem lies, now.

Comment: I suspect it is a Windows specific issue, I'll test with my Linux box. In case you're interested, I'll update my progress in this post.

Thanks, you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
gst-launch-0.10 -vvvv rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.250.100:554 latency=100 ! \
application/x-rtp,media="video",payload=99,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name="H264"  ! \
rtph264depay !  ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink
```

this worked for me with a "Grandtec Electronic MegaPixel WIFI CAM"

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one.

**`gst-launch-0.10 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://10.107.2.217/StreamingSetting?version=1.0&action=getRTSPStream&ChannelID=1&ChannelName=Channel1"
user-id=admin user-pw=admin123 
caps=" application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264,payload=(int)96,ssrc=(uint)237526004,clock-base=(uint)1584170994,seqnum-base=(uint)42626" port=554 ! rtph264depay queue-delay=0 ! h264parse ! decodebin2 ! queue leaky=1 ! autovideosink`**

Its also work when your streaming on Network is secure,and its works on

`rtsp://10.107.2.217`

`RTSP Port : 554`

`Video Codec : H.264`

Hope, its helpful to you guys.